# How to use cloud storage as shared folder within Synology?

Tags: backup, sync, nas, cloud

Is it possible to have a Synology Shared Folder use Cloud Storage? For example I have 2TB of storage space on my Google Drive and want to use that Space (well, some of it) as Shared Folder within Synology. Is that something that could work, maybe with some voodoo on the commandline ?

I have a Synology DS215j.

So far I've seen "Cloud Sync" on Synology which just allows (to my current knowledge) a already existing local storage to sync up to the cloud. Which means the files must exist locally first, which I dont want if possible)

Comment: So that when you download it, it looks like you're downloading from Synology, but it's actually pulling files from Google Drive and sending them to you? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: No. I want a 100GB (example) external Shared Folder which is not locally allocated but uses Cloud Storage.

Comment: Ok, I get it. So when you try to download a file from that folder, what actually happens?

Comment: I'm more talking about upload. When I add files to this folder, it uploads them directly to cloud storage. The files appear as local, but are actually not. I dont know if thats even possible or not. Something like webdav comes into mind which is close to that, right?

Comment: WebDAV is loosely related, it's just a protocol (ie. how file server and client talk to each other). It doesn't define actual storage methods. I think it would be possible to make a  Dropbox proxy that uses WebDAV to expose its content, but that's unrelated to Synology and not offered by it by default. What problem are you actually trying to solve? I mean, what's the point of doing that?

Comment: I dont have enough local space storage available, hence I thought I could go directly to Cloud without the need to put the files locally first. ;)